# ClassNotFound - adding Third Party Jar to Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

OK I'm new to this and struggling so please bear with me!

I'm attempting to add this to an existing web app

https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanJava

The instructions on the page suggest building the Jar with Maven which I've done. I've then tried several ways to get the compiled Jar into my web app project, for example

adding as a dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tincan</groupId>
        <artifactId>tincan</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/tincan-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Or installing

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\workspace\tincanJava\TinCanJava\target\tincan-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -DgroupId=com.rusticsoftware.tincan -DartifactId=tincan -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

I can see the files and classes in Intellij, all elements are showing, however when I run the application I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rusticisoftware.tincan.StatementsQueryInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:509)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Am I doing this wrong? Should I be adding the source to my directory and the dependencies to my POM and building that way?

Answer (score 1):

Scope `system` is the same as scope `provided` that means that this jar is not included in your dependencies. You have to add it to the classpath when running your application

From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> **System**
>
> This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the
>   JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and
>   is not looked up in a repository.
>
> **Provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a
>   container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when
>   building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
>   set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
>   scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This
>   scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is
>   not transitive

Comment: Stupid question - where should the jar live? Is in the src directory the right place?

Comment: @user5839 no src is only for source files. If you use maven, the best place is your mvn repo. or any Folder which is in the classpath